# How to fetch latest entry done in a table for every minute, for every parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have records in tables saved like this:

```
ID | PID   | Param  | Param Value | Date time             |
---|-------|--------|-------------|------------------------
1  | 195   |Param 1 |    12       |2015-11-25 17:41:05.000
2  | 211   |Param 2 |    13       |2015-11-25 17:41:05.000
3  | 195   |Param 1 |    14       |2015-11-25 17:41:35.000
4  | 211   |Param 2 |    15       |2015-11-25 17:41:35.000
5  | 195   |Param 1 |    16       |2015-11-25 17:42:05.000
6  | 211   |Param 2 |    17       |2015-11-25 17:42:05.000
7  | 195   |Param 1 |    16       |2015-11-25 17:42:35.000
8  | 211   |Param 2 |    17       |2015-11-25 17:42:35.000
```

Data for each param comes multiple times each minute and i want to find data for each param that came latest in every minute that is to say:
Suppose data for param 1 came 3 times between 2015-11-25 17:41:00.000 and 2015-11-25 17:42:00.000 so I want the data that came the third time and this needs to be done for every param.

So my result data-set as per above entries should be like:

```
ID | PID   | Param | Param Value | Date time             |
-----------------+----------------------------------------
3  | 195   |Param 1 |    14      |2015-11-25 17:41:35.000
4  | 211   |Param 2 |    15      |2015-11-25 17:41:35.000
7  | 195   |Param 1 |    16      |2015-11-25 17:42:35.000
8  | 211   |Param 2 |    17      |2015-11-25 17:42:35.000
```

I have tried grouping by partitioning and stuff...but it doesn't seem to work. Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With the window function and partition by Datepart

```
Select * 
From (
       Select *
             ,RN = Row_Number() over (Partition By PID,Param ,datepart(MI,[Date time]) Order by [Date time] Desc)
       From  YourTable
    ) A
Where RN=1
```

Returns

```
ID  PID Param   Param Value Date time               RN
3   195 Param 1 14          2015-11-25 17:41:35.000 1
7   195 Param 1 16          2015-11-25 17:42:35.000 1
4   211 Param 2 15          2015-11-25 17:41:35.000 1
8   211 Param 2 17          2015-11-25 17:42:35.000 1
```